# Derivative of signal is normally distributed - why?

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution

I stumbled upon something while analyzing some of my data and don't know the answer to this. There seems to be some sort of drift in my measurement system and I wanted to know more about it. I measured a signal with some amplitude and phase as given in the image below. Now, when I take the derivative of either amplitude or phase and take the histogram of it, the result is normally distributed. What does that mean? I have little background in statistics, and appreciate any source that you could also provide on this.
Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: there's noise in data, you're showing it here

Comment: For a strong clue, plot the autocorrelation function: it will exhibit strong positive lag-one correlation. You can model the signal at time $t$ as a true signal plus noise, $y_t+\epsilon_t.$ Your derivatives are proportional to the first differences $y_{t+1}-y_t + \delta_t$ where $\delta_t = \epsilon_{t+1}-\epsilon_t.$ You are sampling so rapidly that $y_{t+1}-y_t$ is small compared to the SD of $\delta.$ Your histograms therefore show, to a close approximation, the distribution of the $\delta_t.$ *Differences of independent identically distributed random variables tend to look Normal.*

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing what you are supposed to see, as per the comment by @Aksakal. I put together a little simulation model to try to duplicate what you had in the left images, ignoring scale factors and units. This is shown in the figure below:

[image: Simulation model 1]

The raw temporal output is the sum of 1) the step response of a simple RC low pass filter, 2) a sinewave and 3) Gaussian white noise. The simulation step size was 1 ms and all other parameters are shown on the figure. The raw response (black), plus the differentiated response (red), are shown on the next figure:

[image: Raw and diff responses]

Then I ran the simulation 1000 times and binned the resulting 4,096,000 values from the differentiated response. The histogram is shown in the final figure:

[image: Histogram]

So this is just a matter of linearity.

Answer (score 2):

@EdV's answer provides a very standard constructed model that has a Gaussian/Normal error term, which is a very common model for time series.

A very natural question might be *why* is the error term Gaussian? To be clear, it's frequently not! But when it does occur, a natural explanation is something like the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem). This theorem<sup>1</sup> tells us that if we have a random variable that is the average of many independent random variables, the distribution of this average will approach a normal distribution asymptotically, even if the individual variables are not normal distributed themselves. I'm doing a little handwaving here, but if the noise in your recordings are the result of a summation of a large number of much smaller errors of all roughly the same magnitude, it would make sense that this observed noise would be approximately normally distributed.

<sup>1</sup> Actually there are many, many different versions of the central limit theorem out there that apply under different conditions. **The** central limit theorem I'm referring to is the one they teach in stats 101.